# Loop through each row, create button for each record. Cannot get image from database

Tags: vb.net, image, sql-server-ce

I have a form that I am trying to populate with a control for each item on my database (SQLCe). Problem is that one of the items I am trying to return from the database is an image. However, my original code gave me an error:

```
Value of type "Byte' cannot be converted to 'System.Drawing.Image'
```

Here is my original code

```
Private Sub btnCategories_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCategories.Click

    Dim dt As DataTable = ProducT_CATEGORYTableAdapter.GetData

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows

        Dim btn As New btnCategoryTabs()

        btn.lblCategoryName.Name = DirectCast(row("Category_Name"), String)
        btn.lblCategoryName.Text = btn.lblCategoryName.Name
        btn.picPCategoryPicture.Image = DirectCast(row("Image"), Byte) 'Error Here'

        'Add categories to the Panel
        flpMainPanel.Controls.Add(btn)

    Next

End Sub
```

I am sure that I have to convert the image, so I started messing around with this bit of code:

```
  Dim Stream As New MemoryStream()
     Dim image As Byte() = CType('Can't figure out what to put here), Byte())
     Stream.Write(image, 0, image.Length)
     Dim bitmap As New Bitmap(Stream)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have stored image data in your database then it would be a `Byte()` i.e. and array, not just a single `Byte`.  You then have to convert that `Byte` array to an `Image`.  You're on the right track.  Here's one I prepared earlier:

```
Dim connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT Picture FROM MyTable WHERE ID = 1", connection)

connection.Open()

Dim pictureData As Byte() = DirectCast(command.ExecuteScalar(), Byte())

connection.Close()

Dim picture As Image = Nothing

'Create a stream in memory containing the bytes that comprise the image.'
Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream(pictureData)
    'Read the stream and create an Image object from the data.'
    picture = Image.FromStream(stream)
End Using
```

http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?469562-Saving-Images-in-Databases&highlight=

In your case specifically, that becomes:

```
'Create a stream in memory containing the bytes that comprise the image.'
Using stream As New IO.MemoryStream(DirectCast(row("Image"), Byte()))
    'Read the stream and create an Image object from the data.'
    btn.picPCategoryPicture.Image = Image.FromStream(stream)
End Using
```